# I've been trying to create a custom terminal command, but I am getting a syntax error all the way

Tags: github, terminal

```
import sys
import os
from github import Github

path = "/Users/logaprasannaramkumar/Development/ThatProjects/New"


username = "" #Insert your github username here
password = "" #Insert your github password here

def create():
    folderName = str(sys.argv[1])
    os.makedirs(path + str(folderName)
    user = Github(username, password).get_user()
    repo = user.create_repo(folderName)
    print("Succesfully created repository {}".format(folderName))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create()
```

All I've been getting is this syntax error.

I tried changing the code but it doesn't really have any effect.

Error:

> invalid syntax (, line 14)pylint(syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
os.makedirs(path + str(folderName)
```

should be

```
os.makedirs(path + str(folderName))
```